# Como fazer alocação dinâmica de uma string

Tags: c

Bom eu queria alocar dinamicamente vários nomes em c, eu já sei como fazer só normal mas queira como vou mostrar aqui no código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char *nome;
  nome = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 80); // normal

  char nomes[10][100] // aqui são 10 nomes com 100 caracteres, queira alocar essa parte

   free(nome);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Zeero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perceba que uma String é um Vetor de Caracteres, então alocar um Vetor de Strings é basicamente uma **Matriz de Caracteres**, para alocar dinamicamente uma Matriz de Caracteres você precisa fazer isso, especificamente para seu exemplo de 10 nomes de 100 caracteres:

```
char **nomes; //Observe que é um ponteiro para um ponteiro
nomes = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10); //Aqui você aloca 10 ponteiros de char, ou seja, 10 strings **vazias**, ainda **não alocadas**.
```

Agora você precisa alocar cada uma dessas strings, da seguinte forma:

```
for(indice=0;indice<10;indice++) //Loop para percorrer todos os índices do seu "vetor"
    nomes[indice]=malloc(sizeof(char)*100); //String Dinâmica Normal
```

A partir deste ponto você pode utilizar normalmente, como se fosse um vetor de strings, mas note que será necessário liberar cada uma das alocações feitas, uma para o vetor de strings e uma para cada uma das 10 strings, portanto, terá de liberar todas as 11 alocações realizadas, desta forma:

```
for(indice=0;indice<10;indice++) //Percorre o "Vetor"
    free(nomes[indice]); //Libera a String
free(nomes); //No término do Loop, libera o "Vetor"
```

Desta forma não haverá nenhum **Memory Leak** e você terá alocado um vetor de strings dinâmico corretamente.